# (Anova) DCR with Subsamples using R

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to solve a DCR (Design Completely Randomsize) exercise, for example this is the data sheet
[image: table]

in R extract data

```r
tb = data.frame("treat" = factor(x =  rep(1:2, c(12,10)),
                              labels = c("M1","M2")),
            "samp" = factor(x = c(rep(1,2), rep(2,3), rep(3,5), rep(4,2),
                                     rep(1,3),rep(2,3), rep(3,4)),
                               labels = c("s1","s2","s3","s4")), 
            "value" = c(5.6,5.7,
                        5.0,5.0,5.1,
                        5.4,5.4,5.4,5.5,5.4,
                        5.3,5.5,
                        7.6,7.6,7.8,
                        7.4,7.0,7.2,
                        7.5,7.6,7.5,7.4))
fit = aov(formula = value ~ treat * samp,data = tb)
anova(fit)
```

but the **result is different** from this

[image]

if you compare the above table with `anova(fit)`, are different. Well my question itself is: is there a library that solves problems equal to this, with balanced and unbalanced sampling

Comment: I don't understand what your question is...

Comment: @Werner good is that the result of `anova()` is different, I don't know if there is any other library for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State your question more precisely. What exactly is your issue? What 'other library' are you looking for?

Generally:
Your data is, as you mentioned, unbalanced. In this case, the choice of reduction in residual sum of squares (Type I, II or III) produce different outcomes. That is a mathematical issue, not one of R. In addition, since Type I  (that's what you chose) is sequential, the ordering of the model terms is relevant. I.e. compare

`fit = aov(formula = value ~ treat * samp, data = tb) anova(fit)`

with

`fit = aov(formula = value ~ samp * treat, data = tb) anova(fit)`.

Perhaps it helps.

Comment: I understand, now how would I get the average **876.9641**?